# Sending files from phone to notebook via Bluetooth

Tags: files, bluetooth

I've installed elementary OS Loki on my Lenovo G580 laptop and I'm very happy with it, but there's a one problem.
In elementary OS Freya (and any other Linux distros I've ever used) I used to send files (usually pictures) from phone (Samsung Galaxy S3 mini) to the laptop via Bluetooth.

It needed to tick specific option in `gnome-file-share-properties`, but it works after that.

But in Loki, it just doesn't work. I've enabled files receiving via Bluetooth in System settings -> Sharing and in the `gnome-file-share-properties`, but if I try to send file from phone, it fails (but elementary OS knows that I'm trying to send something, because there is a small white dot at the bottom right corner of wingpanel's Bluetooth icon).

Phone and laptop are paired and I am able to send files from laptop to phone using "Send files via Bluetooth" option in file manager.

Does anyone know what should I do?

Thanks for your help.

[image: My System settings -> Sharing]
[image: Settings in gnome-file-share-properties]

Comment: Did you solved the problem somehow? Please post any updates since I can't figure it out myself, either.

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure why it got flagged. However the last version of elementary is 5.1.7 Hera so you might want to update the question to reflect the current state.